# Primefaces: hideEvent of overlayPanel should be depending on showEvent

Tags: jquery, primefaces, jquery-events

Our code generates several `<div>` boxes (with the custom tag `own:resourceDiagramElement`). Now we try to bind to each `<div>` box an overlay panel with the following **TWO** behaviours:

1. If the mouse moves over the `<div>` box/elements the OverlayPanel should show some details infos about the `<div>` box/element. If the mouse moves out of the `<div>` box, the OverlayPanel should be hidden.
2. If you click on a `<div>` box/element the OverplayPanel should be showed and KEEP open until you click again an the `<div>` box/element. Like you have clicked on the `<div>` box, nothing should be happened if the mouse moves out of the `<div>` box range.

Basically the source code looks this:

```
<c:forEach items="#{resourceStateDiagramViewBean.graphicalResources}" var="resource1">

<own:resourceStateDiagramElement id="#{resource1.id}"
onClick="alert('alert')" top="#{resource1.top}"
left="#{resource1.left}" width="#{resource1.width}"
height="#{resource1.height}" styleClass="#{resource1.styleClass}"
showText="#{resourceStateDiagramViewBean.showText}" />
...
<p:overlayPanel id="panel_#{resource1.id}" for="#{resource1.id}" 
showEvent="mouseover OR mouseclick" hideEvent="mouseleave OR mouseclick" >
...
</c:forEach>
```

Our custom tag `<own:resourceStateDiagramElement>` produces html code like:

```
<div id="facility_01" class="resource-element-default" style="top:1%; 
left:2%; width:5%; height:2%;">
```

It means that `hideEvent` should depend on the way/event the the panel was showed...
We tried to bind and unbind events on the `<div>` elements, but it looks like that primesfaces events are overrides this own binds.

How we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution. I defined the showEvent & hideEvent with **null**.
...
    
    ...
    
    ...
The Bean method GetJavascriptsForOverlayPanel produces the following Java Script code:

```
    <script id="facility_01_script" type="text/javascript"> 


    var facility_01_useMouseLeaveEnter_Event = true;
    var facility_02_useMouseLeaveEnter_Event = true;
    var facility_0X_useMouseLeaveEnter_Event = true;
    ...

    window.onload = function () {   
        $("#facility_01").bind('click',function(){
            if (facility_01_useMouseLeaveEnter_Event) {
                widget_panel_facility_01.show();
                facility_01_useMouseLeaveEnter_Event = false;
            }else {
                widget_panel_facility_01.hide();
                facility_01_useMouseLeaveEnter_Event = true;
        }});

        $("#facility_01").bind('mouseenter',function(){
            if (facility_01_useMouseLeaveEnter_Event) {
                widget_panel_facility_01.show();
        }});

        $("#facility_01").bind('mouseleave',function(){
            if (facility_01_useMouseLeaveEnter_Event) {
                widget_panel_facility_01.hide();
        }});


        $("#facility_02").bind('click',function(){
            ...
        }});

        $("#facility_02").bind('mouseenter',function(){
            ...
        }});

        $("#facility_02").bind('mouseleave',function(){
            ...
        }});        

        ...
         < code for facility_0X element >

    };
</script>
```

With this I got the acceptable solution. 
Unfortunately it isn't possible to keep two OverlayPanels open at the same time. As soon as you try to open a second panel. The first will be closed. May this default behaviour of an OverplayPanel?